# C#: making a class usable in foreach

Tags: c#, ienumerable, primes

I'm having a little problem with this thing:
I have to make a PrimeCollection class in C# that implements IEnumerable interface and generates prime numbers collection on the fly.

So if I write as a test something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    PrimeCollection pc = new PrimeCollection();
    foreach (int p in pc)
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

It should generate primes until it reaches int32 limit.

So far I have this:

```
class PrimeCollection {
    public IEnumerable<int> Primes() {
        var ints = Enumerable.Range(2, Int32.MaxValue - 1);
        return ints.Where(x => !ints.TakeWhile(y => y < Math.Sqrt(x)).Any(y => x % y == 0));
    }
}
```

However to do the generating i need to call out it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    PrimeCollection pc = new PrimeCollection();
    foreach (int p in pc.Primes())
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I assume I need to make the class IEnumerable, not the method, however I have no idea how to generate the numbers on the fly.

Comment: You can read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I) tutorial, if you want to implement `IEnumerable` in your custom Collection class

Comment: Have a look at yield return, that is what you need to return a series of primes.

Comment: there is a **bug** right in there (the way I see it you will have 4,9,... in your collection - and btw: better do `y*y <= x` instead of `y < Math.Sqrt(x)` ;))

Comment: If you know you want all primes up to `int.MaxValue` you might want to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specifically create your custom primes-enumerable, you can define it as a wrapper over your existing linq query. Like this:

```
public class PrimesEnumerable : IEnumerable<int> {
    public PrimesEnumerable() {
        var ints = Enumerable.Range(2, Int32.MaxValue - 1);
        _internalEnumerable = ints.Where(x => !ints.TakeWhile(y => y*y<=x).Any(y => x % y == 0));
    }
    public readonly IEnumerable<int> _internalEnumerable;

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
        return _internalEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return _internalEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can foreach over it:

```
var primes = new PrimesEnumerable();

int i = 0;
foreach (var prime in primes) {
    if (i == 10)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine(prime);
    i++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Note: do fix the bug that @CarstenKönig is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to have an instantiable class at all. You are not holding a state.

```
public static class Prime
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Values() 
    {
        var ints = Enumerable.Range(2, Int32.MaxValue - 1);
        return ints.Where(x => !ints.TakeWhile(y => y < Math.Sqrt(x)).Any(y => x % y == 0));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    foreach (int p in Prime.Values())
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not my desired effect. I need to use it like in my first example. I need to use foreach on a class

Comment: If the reason is that this is a homework and your teacher requires it, that's ok. Just see the other solution. If you have other reasons, maybe you should think about them. You gain nothing, except more code to have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I understand, however that was required in the excercise I had to do. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach(var prime in new PrimeCollection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prime);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class PrimeCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        var ints = Enumerable.Range(2, Int32.MaxValue - 1);
        return ints.Where(x => !ints.TakeWhile(y => y < Math.Sqrt(x)).Any(y => x % y == 0)).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```